# Triggering mouse/touch events in Matter.js

Tags: matter.js

How would one go about adding programmatically triggered touch/mouse events in Matter.js?  I have a few collision events set up for the engine, but can not trigger a mouseup event that stops the current dragging action.  I've tried various combinations of targeting the canvas element, the mouse/mouseConstraint, and the non-static body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out I had incorrectly configured the Matter.Mouse module, and was re-assigning the mouse input that had already been set in MouseConstraint.  The following works in regards to my original question:

```
Matter.mouseConstraint.mouse.mouseup(event);
```

Answer (score 3):

If you, like me, came here trying to figure out how to be able to click on a Matter.js body object, let me give you one way. My goal in my project was to assign some attributes to my rectangle objects and call a function when they were clicked on.

The first thing to do was to distinguish between dragging and clicking, so I wrote(using Jquery):

```
        $("body").on("mousedown", function(e){
        mouseX1 = e.pageX;
        mouseY1 = e.pageY;
    });

    $("body").on("mouseup", function(e){
        mouseX2 = e.pageX;
        mouseY2 = e.pageY;
        if((mouseX1 == mouseX2) && (mouseY1 == mouseY2)){
                //alert("click!\n" + mouseX2 + " " + mouseY2 +"\n");
                var bodiesUnder = Matter.Query.point(books, { x: mouseX2, y: mouseY2 });
                //alert("click!\n" + mouseX2 + " " + mouseY2 +"\n");

                if (bodiesUnder.length > 0) {
                var bodyToClick = bodiesUnder[0];
                alert(bodyToClick.title2);
            }
        }
    });
```

This was accomplished when listening for "mouseup" and asking if ((mouseX1 == mouseX2) && (mouseY1 == mouseY2)).

Second- the juicy part- create a var array to hold the objects, or 'bodies', we are going to dig up under the mouse. Thankfully there's this function:

```
var bodiesUnder = Matter.Query.point(books, { x: mouseX2, y: mouseY2 });
```

For the first element in here I entered "books". For you this needs to be the name of an array you've put all your objects, or 'bodies' into. If you don't have them in an array, it's not hard to throw them all in, like so:

```
var books = [book1, book2, book3];
```

Once that was all done, I was able to alert(book1.title2) to see what the title of that book (body) is. My bodies were coded as follows:

```
        var book2 = Bodies.rectangle(390, 200, 66, 70, {
        render : {
            sprite : {
                texture: "img/tradingIcon.jpg"
            }
        },
        restitution : 0.3,
        title1 : 'Vanessa and Terry',
        title2 : 'Trading'
    });
```

Hope that helps! This one had me hung up for a whole day.